# Why is it not possible to connect to my server using RSA from an Ubuntu machine?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, openssh

I tried to connect to my server using

```
ssh xxxx@xxxxxxx.xxx
```

The result was:

```
Unable to negotiate with xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-dss
```

Then I ran

```
ssh xxxx@xxxxxxx.xxx -G
```

with the output

```
user xxxx
hostname xxxxxxx.xxx
port 22
addressfamily any
batchmode no
canonicalizefallbacklocal yes
canonicalizehostname false
challengeresponseauthentication yes
checkhostip yes
compression no
controlmaster false
enablesshkeysign no
exitonforwardfailure no
fingerprinthash SHA256
forwardagent no
forwardx11 no
forwardx11trusted yes
gatewayports no
gssapiauthentication yes
gssapidelegatecredentials no
hashknownhosts yes
hostbasedauthentication no
identitiesonly no
kbdinteractiveauthentication yes
nohostauthenticationforlocalhost no
passwordauthentication yes
permitlocalcommand no
protocol 2
proxyusefdpass no
pubkeyauthentication yes
requesttty auto
rhostsrsaauthentication no
rsaauthentication yes
streamlocalbindunlink no
stricthostkeychecking ask
tcpkeepalive yes
tunnel false
useprivilegedport no
verifyhostkeydns false
visualhostkey no
updatehostkeys false
canonicalizemaxdots 1
compressionlevel 6
connectionattempts 1
forwardx11timeout 1200
numberofpasswordprompts 3
serveralivecountmax 3
serveraliveinterval 0
ciphers chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
hostkeyalgorithms ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
hostbasedkeytypes ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
kexalgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
loglevel INFO
macs umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
pubkeyacceptedkeytypes ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
xauthlocation /usr/bin/xauth
identityfile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
identityfile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
identityfile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
identityfile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
canonicaldomains
globalknownhostsfile /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2
userknownhostsfile ~/.ssh/known_hosts ~/.ssh/known_hosts2
sendenv LANG
sendenv LC_*
connecttimeout none
tunneldevice any:any
controlpersist no
escapechar ~
ipqos lowdelay throughput
rekeylimit 0 0
streamlocalbindmask 0177
```

I added my public key (from `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the server (starting with `ssh-rsa`) which worked quite well at least until the last Ubuntu update (even today from a Linux Mint machine - different key, but also rsa).

On the Ubuntu I'm using `OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016` (I don't know the ssh version from the Mint machine; the server runs CentOS, i think)

**What am I doing wrong?**

Just for fun I added:

```
# http://www.openssh.com/legacy.html
Host xxxxxxx.xxx
    HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-dss
```

to the `.ssh/config`.

The connection is successful, but then I have to type my password all the time, since the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` does not have a public dsa key.

So why does ssh using RSA does not work from my Ubuntu `16.04 LTS` machine?

Comment: The host key and client key aren't related. openssh 7.0+ _client_ needs HostKeyAlgorithms to accept DSA key for _host_, but then if your client has an RSA private key and that RSA public key is in the server's `authorized_keys` it should work. Try `-v` or even `-vv` and see details of what it tries and the results. (FYI output from `-v` includes the server's version.)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: Finally it worked with adding `HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-dss` to the `.ssh/config`, thanks. It did not work with automatic login previously, since the rsa-key from the account I'm working with was actually missing in the `authorized_keys` file. Can you please copy your comment to an answer, I'd like to accept it.